# When an email message is Opened the system does not seem to recognize that it has been updated for Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, emailmessage

I have created a flow on the `EmailMessage` Object that is supposed to run anytime an email message record is created or updated if it is related to a specific Customer Object record.

- On the related record I am trying to update how many emails have been sent but also when the email message was opened by the recipient.
- The count of how many have been sent works fine and in debugging
  within the flow the opened date also works fine but when actually
  sending an email the custom field for the open date never gets
  populated despite the email message showing that it has been opened.
- I tried running debug logs and it had a log for the email message
  being created but despite changing from not opened to opened the
  email message didn't have an additional debug log for an update of any kind.
- Does salesforce just not consider changing the open date and isopened field to true an actual "update" to the email message object record?  Has anyone else encountered this issue?

**Details on Flow**

- Flow is on Email Message object record
- Trigger When: A record is created or updated
- Entry Conditions: RelatedToId starts with a0f
- When to Run the Flow for Updated Records: Every time a record is updated and meets the condition requirements.
- Optimize the Flow for: Actions & Related Records

Run Immediately
Get related record
Decisions of:
IS NEW - Record IsNew() (Formula field checks if IsNew this works fine)
Is Opened - First Opened ISCHANGED OR First Opened ISSET

I believe I also tried "First Opened" isNUll False but that part doesn't matter at the moment because as I said previously I'm not even getting an email message going into the flow when the Open field is changed to show that it has been opened.

Thanks,
Amanda

Comment: Sadly the idea on the ideaexchange says "Delivered" but it doesn't actually do what was requested.